# embedding php in html code

Tags: php, html, embedding

```
<? php $text = "hello world"; ?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>">
```

in the browser gives me an input box with value:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: text in **C:\xampp\htdocs\FIRST-PROJECT\index.php** on line **26**

Comment: this obviously isn't full code nor actual code for that matter. Why don't you show us what you're really using? seeing an input, tells me you're using a form.

Answer (score 1):

`<? php` isn't a valid tag, so you're never creating `$text`. There is an extra space in there.   Close the space after the `?`, and make it `<?php`.

Comment: all this code is in a php file

Comment: Fine, that doesn't stop `<? php` from being an invalid PHP tag.

Comment: @mpassad I think you are misreading the answer

Comment: they didn't post full or actual code. Misleading on the OP's part.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not so sure of that (minus the closing `?>`);  it's a simple Hello world, so I'm not sure what else would be there

Comment: did you see my comment to them under their question? @nomistic

Comment: aha! good point. that could be it, or it could be complete misunderstanding.  It must be time for a break. :)